# What are the steps to simplify this matrix?

Tags: matrices

From a Quantum Computing course that I'm following. I am trying to figure out what are the steps to simplify this matrix. The answer is **-0.23**:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}&-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}i \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 &-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\\\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}i \end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm really rusty (bad) with matrix algebra, so I can't find a way to solve this.

Comment: Just take it one step at a time.  Remember that these operations are associative... that is to say $a\cdot b \cdot c\cdot d = ((a\cdot b)\cdot c)\cdot d=a\cdot (b\cdot (c\cdot d)))$.  If you are unable to do even one of the steps, then that is where an explanation should start.  Ignoring the somewhat messy numbers for now, do you know how to do the multiplication $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}e\\f\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: This just follows the usual rules for matrix multiplication, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition for example. You need to do little work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is in the form

$$c\cdot \vec v^HA \vec v$$

and the result is a scalar.

To proceed we can at first calculate

$$\vec w=A \vec v=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 &-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\\\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}i \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}i \\\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}i \end{bmatrix}$$

then

$$\vec v^HA \vec v=\vec v^H\vec w=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}&-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}i \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}i \\\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}i \end{bmatrix}=\frac13-\frac23=-\frac13$$

and finally

$$c\cdot \vec v^HA \vec v=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\frac13\right)\approx -0.236$$